# Content managment system for Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, content-management-system

I need to create website for news. So I want to suggest what kind of technologies I can use with Nodejs back end side.I mean CMS for nodejs and other staff. Thanks for attention and for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would recommend either Keystone js or Ghost. It's well documented and broadly used.

https://ghost.org/

http://keystonejs.com/

However here u can find a article with the 8 best CMS system to use with Nodejs, so I would recommend you read that as well

https://www.slant.co/topics/1847/~node-js-based-cms

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for article